# Should we Switch From Nant To Msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant

currently we use nant, ccnet (cruise), svn, Nant,. I use msbuild to do my sln build just because it was simpler to shell out.

Are there any merits to switching my whole build script to MSBuild?

I need to be able to run unit tests, deploy. Is this easier?

Comment: If you already have it working, why bother changing?

Comment: Compatibility issues are always there and top of it change request coming alexn, thats why to heads up !!FYIAK!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know people that swear by one or the other and have written scripts in both.  I usually use NAnt and call MSBuild for sln/proj files on some projects like you are.  With ASP.Net stuff, it's just simpler this way.

With that said, .net 4 works with NAnt and while there hasn't been any huge updates in NAnt for a while, there's still people working on it.  There's an assortment of plugins/extensions for it, and it's something you already have in place.

If it's not broke, I wouldn't change.